# Change all file endings via batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to change all file endings in one folder from `.sic` to `.edi` via a windows batch file. As I usually don't work with cmd or else (mostly doing html work...), I don't really know how to start this. I couldn't find an existing question matching my requirements either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following single line should do it!

```bat
Ren "YourFolderPath\*.sic" *.edi
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
ren *.sic *.edi
```

Just create a batch file with that line, or just go into Command Prompt and type it in manually.

This is one use case where Windows batch is easier than Linux shells.